# how to read current character from what stdout console cursor pointing on

Tags: c++, stdout

I'm writing code where only the cursor of the console is moving and not necessarily becauase of keyboard input.
i need a simple way/function to read current char from what the cursor of stdout is currently pointing on.
any suggestions?

(Windows 10,win32 application via VS 2017)

Comment: What operating system?  What terminal?  Please also describe your requirements more clearly.  It's possible that you _think_ you have to solve whatever they are by knowing the character under the console's cursor, when in fact you're approaching the problem wrong (XY Problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally succeeded(Windows).
the answer to whoever also needed this:

```
char cursorCharRead()
{
    char buf[BUFSIZ];
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbiInfo;
    HANDLE hConsole= GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hConsole, &csbiInfo);
    COORD pos = csbiInfo.dwCursorPosition; //set pos to current cursor location
    TCHAR strFromConsole[1];    //need space to only one char
    DWORD dwChars;
    ReadConsoleOutputCharacter(
    hConsole,
    strFromConsole, // Buffer where store symbols
    1, // Read 1 char to strFormConsole
    pos, // Read from current cursor position
    &dwChars); // How many symbols stored
char c = strFromConsole[0];
return c;
```

}

this function will return the char the cursor of the console is currently pointing on

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there's no portable way to do so.

On Windows, [ReadConsoleOutputCharacter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleoutputcharacter). To find out cursor position, call [GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolescreenbufferinfo).

On Linux, [mvinch](https://linux.die.net/man/3/inch) from `<curses.h>` will read characters. To find out where to read, [getyx](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getyx).

On other platforms it’s something different.

Comment: thank,ReadConsoleOutputCharacter is what i need ! however, i didn't succeeded understanding how to actually get the char from it, a help would  be very appreciated.