# How can I make the input to get inserted instead of overwritten on the console?

Tags: c++

I wrote the following header file and included in my code:

```
#define ARROW_RIGHT 77
#define BACKSPACE 8
#define INSERT 82
#define F1 59
#define F2 60
#define F3 61
#define F5 63
#define SPECIAL_KEY(x) (x==0 || x==0xE0)

//Global variable for screen dimensions
COORD dims;

/*Note: the following method allows you to write a writer a character
anywhere on the screen. It moves the screen cursor to the same position as well.*/
void gotoxy(int xpos, int ypos, int col, char ch)
{
    COORD scrn;
    HANDLE hOuput = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    scrn.X = xpos; scrn.Y = ypos;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hOuput, scrn);
    HANDLE  screen = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(screen, col);
    DWORD useless;
    WriteConsole(screen, &ch, 1, (LPDWORD)&useless, NULL);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(screen, 15);
    SMALL_RECT windowSize = { 0, 0, 100, 100 };
    SetConsoleWindowInfo(screen, TRUE, &windowSize);
}

void GetConsoleWindowDims() {
    HANDLE hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbiInfo;
    SMALL_RECT srctWindow;
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hStdout, &csbiInfo);
    srctWindow = csbiInfo.srWindow;
    dims.X = srctWindow.Right;
    dims.Y = srctWindow.Bottom;
}

COORD GetConsoleCursorPosition(HANDLE hConsoleOutput)
{
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO cbsi;
    if (GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hConsoleOutput, &cbsi))
    {
        return cbsi.dwCursorPosition;
    }
    else
    {
        // The function failed. Call GetLastError() for details.
        COORD invalid = { 0, 0 };
        return invalid;
    }
}

void moveScreenCursorLeft() {
    HANDLE hOuput = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD pos = GetConsoleCursorPosition(hOuput);
    if (pos.X > 0)
        pos.X--;
    else if (pos.Y > 0) {
        pos.Y--;
        pos.X = dims.X;
    }
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hOuput, pos);
}

void moveScreenCursorRight() {
    HANDLE hOuput = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD pos = GetConsoleCursorPosition(hOuput);
    if (pos.X < dims.X)
        pos.X++;
    else if (pos.Y < dims.Y) {
        pos.Y++;
        pos.X = 0;
    }
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hOuput, pos);
}

#endif // TEENY_H_INCLUDED
```

And my code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Teeny.h"
using namespace std;

//Skeleton of class LinkedText
class LinkedText{
    struct Node{
        char ch;
        Node * next;
        Node * prev;
    } *head, *tail, *cursorPos;

    int textSize;

    public:
        LinkedText(){
            head=tail=cursorPos=NULL;
            textSize=0;
        }
        //All these methods (except copying) are O(1) thanks to the linked list!
        void addCharAtCursorPos(char input);//when char entered
        void delCharAtCursorPos();//when bksp pressed
        void moveCursorRight();//right arrow
        void moveCursorLeft();//left arrow
        /*the following method returns the sub-list after cutting,
        and also adjusts cursor position*/
        Node * cutTextBetween(Node * cursorpos1, Node * cursorpos2);
        Node * copyTextBetween(Node * cursorpos1, Node * cursorpos2);
        void insertTextAtCursorPos(Node * subList);

       
        int findInText(const string & key);

        //You may add appropriate printing methods and other methods below
        ~LinkedText(){//add code
        };//delete the list


        /*The methods below will be used to keep
          the screen cursor inside the text area
          only.
        */
        inline bool textToLeft(){
            return (cursorPos!=NULL && cursorPos->prev!=NULL);
        }


        inline bool textToRight(){
            return (cursorPos!=NULL);
        }

};

int main()
{
    GetConsoleWindowDims();

    /*This code is capable of detecting the
      left and right arrow keys; the backspace key;
      the escape key (for quit); the F1, F2 and F3 keys;
      and the regular text keys.
      Written for CS-218 "Data Structures" BCS-3A, FAST-NU, Lahore.*/

    LinkedText text;
    int key;
    while(key!=ESCAPE){
          key=_getch();
          //either an arrow or function key is pressed
          if(SPECIAL_KEY(key)){
              key=_getch();//get 2nd part of code from buffer
              switch(key){
              case ARROW_LEFT:
                  //if(text.textToLeft()){
                    moveScreenCursorLeft();
                    //text.moveCursorLeft();
                  //}
                break;
              case ARROW_RIGHT:
                  //if (text.textToRight()){
                    moveScreenCursorRight();
                    //text.moveCursorRight();
                  //}
                break;
              case F1://start or end text selection
                  cout<<"[F1]";
                break;
              case F2://cut option
                  cout<<"[F2]";
                break;
              case F3://copy option
                  cout<<"[F3]";
                break;
              case F5://for search
                  cout<<"[F5]";
                break;
              case INSERT://to insert text
                cout<<"[INSERT]";
                break;
              };
          }else if(key==BACKSPACE){
              cout<<"[BKSP]";
          }else{
              cout<<char(key);
          }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So this code prints the the specified characters and when I move the cursor through arrow keys, it moves accordingly but when I enter any character, it overwrites the character being pointed by the character. But what I want is to insert the character at the cursor position.

Comment: I don't know how nicely C++ IO streams and Windows console commands play together. I suspect poorly. Odds are good that you'll have to use the Windows console API exclusively or use another console library like curses.

Comment: You can maintain your own buffer of characters and overwrites characters carefully, or just [read them back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54994490/how-to-read-current-character-from-what-stdout-console-cursor-pointing-on) and shift them one position across.

Comment: @user202729 could you write a code for that?